# Textarea displaying incorrect character count in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a textarea where i am displaying the character count at the bottom. I am passing the response from API as a prop as i want to display the character count. My onChange function works correctly, i am not passing the data as a props. I am updating my component when i get a API response with the help of useEffect.

But i am facing issue with the count and it is displaying the count incorrectly.
I have attached the snippet of the React Component.

```js
class TextAreaComponent extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    characterCount: '1500'
  };
}

  handleWordCount = (e) => {
    const charCount = e.target.value.length;
    const maxCharCount = e.target.getAttribute("max-length");
    const charLeft = maxCharCount - charCount;
    this.setState({
      characterCount: charLeft
    });
  }

render() {

const { data } = this.props;
// Binding the data in value,
  return (
        <div className="personal-bio">
            <h4>Bio</h4>
            <textarea onChange={this.handleWordCount} value={data && data.length > 0 ? data : ""} max-length="1500" name="textarea" placeholder="Tell me about yourself"></textarea>
              <p className="user-bio-char-limit">Total Character limit : {this.state.characterCount}</p>
            </div>
        )
  }
}

// Passing the response data as props
ReactDOM.render(
  <TextAreaComponent data="Hello, this is my bio" />, document.body
);
```

```css
textarea {
border: 1px solid #222;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 problems here. First, you are not updating the `textarea` value on change. The second problem is you have to calculate the count also when the results came from the API. you can do this work in the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle function but because I don't have access to the API I will use `componentDidMount` just to show what you should do.

```js
class TextAreaComponent extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    characterCount: '1500',
    data: ""
  };
}

componentDidMount() {
    const charCount = this.props.data.length;
    const maxCharCount = this.state.characterCount;
    const charLeft = maxCharCount - charCount;
    this.setState({
      characterCount: charLeft,
      data: this.props.data
    });
}

handleWordCount = (e) => {
    const charCount = e.target.value.length;
    const maxCharCount = e.target.getAttribute("max-length");
    const charLeft = maxCharCount - charCount;
    this.setState({
      characterCount: charLeft,
      data: e.target.value
    });
 }

render() {

const { data } = this.state;
// Binding the data in value,
  return (
        <div className="personal-bio">
            <h4>Bio</h4>
            <textarea onChange={this.handleWordCount} value={data && data.length > 0 ? data : ""} max-length="1500" name="textarea" placeholder="Tell me about yourself"></textarea>
              <p className="user-bio-char-limit">Total Character limit : {this.state.characterCount}</p>
            </div>
        )
  }
}

// Passing the response data as props
ReactDOM.render(
  <TextAreaComponent data="Hello, this is my bio" />, document.body
);
```

```css
textarea {
border: 1px solid #222;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: We can still type below maximum limit reached. it goes in negative...

Answer (score 1):

The character count is initially wrong because you're hard-coding it as `1500` instead of `1500 - props.data.length`. That said, `this.state.characterCount` appears to be a computed value, which is unnecessary to store in state. I would recommend storing the `value` in state, since that is the piece that actually changes. Then, you can compute the remaining characters directly in the render portion of your component. Here's a simplified functional component:

```
const MAX_LENGTH = 1500;

const TextAreaComponent = ({ data }) => {
  // Set the value of `data` as the initial value of the textarea.
  const [value, setValue] = useState(data);

  return (
    <div className="personal-bio">
      <h4>Bio</h4>
      <textarea
        max-length={MAX_LENGTH}
        name="textarea"
        onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="Tell me about yourself"
        value={value}
      />
      <p className="user-bio-char-limit">
        Remaining characters: {MAX_LENGTH - value.length}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-poitras-8gbwd

**Update:** Here's an example where state is completely controlled by the parent. Much simpler, since the Textarea component simply responds to prop changes rather having to sync state and props.

```
const TextAreaComponent = ({ data, onChange }) => (
  <div className="personal-bio">
    <h4>Bio</h4>
    <textarea
      max-length={MAX_LENGTH}
      name="textarea"
      onChange={onChange}
      placeholder="Tell me about yourself"
      value={data}
    />
    <p className="user-bio-char-limit">
      Remaining characters: {MAX_LENGTH - data.length}
    </p>
  </div>
);

const Parent = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState('Hello, this is my bio');

  useEffect(() => {
    // Make your API call here and update state using `setData`
    // when the request finishes.
  }, []);

  return (
    <TextAreaComponent data={data} onChange={(e) => setData(e.target.value)} />
  );
};
```

Comment: Can i set the state in useEffect ... As the data passed as props from api will be passed after the component has been mounted. Passing the data as a second argument in UseEffect. Am i right ?

Comment: @tkamath99: It sounds like you're already setting state using an effect in the parent when the API request finishes. If so, you might consider having the parent control the state, so that the Textarea component simply responds to prop changes. That would be much simpler.

Comment: @tkamath99: I've updated my answer to reflect my comment above.